# Rounding formula in Omnistudio Dataraptors

Tags: formula, omnistudio, rounding, data-raptor

I am currently new to Omnistudio and I am using it to do document generation.

I am extracting data from the Invoice Object and Invoice Lines Object to create an Invoice PDF.

I have a problem implementing the `ROUND` formula to round off the subtotal to two decimal places. Unfortunately, when I preview it, the formula is not rounding it off to 2 decimal places.

Below are the steps on how I attempted to perform the rounding.

1. Extract Data based on recordId
2. Made a formula of `ROUND(%DataOutput%,2)` and made a result path
3. Placed the Result path in the Extract JSON Path for the Output Section.

This is being done in the Extract Data Raptors

Answer (score 0):

I managed to replicate the requirement. I used Quote for this example, but it is relevant for any number/currency field.

1. Extract Data based on `recordId`
2. Created formula `ROUND(%Quote:TotalPrice%,0)` which has a merge field of the `%OBJECT:FIELD%` and defined the formula result path as `FORMULA_TotalPrice`
3. In the output tab, I added `FORMULA_TotalPrice` as the extract JSON path and `Total` as the output JSON path.

I also added a non-round extract JSON property just for comparison:

```json
{
  "Total": 5181,
  "TotalUnrounded": 5181.01
}
```

Here is a screenshot of my formula tab:

[image]

And a screenshot op my output tab:

[image]

Good luck!